# How to stop bed from squeaking

Tags: bedroom, sound

Every time I roll over or get in/out of my bed, it squeaks. This has really started to annoy me. The bed is a metal bedstead with metal springs, and the noise seems to be coming from the springs. Are there any ways I can silence my bed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Loose screws then?!

Comment: I've tightened all the screws in the frame, but it still makes the noise, so I think the noise is coming from the springs.

Comment: Yep,that'll be it - its why I chose wooden slats last time I got a bed...even they creak a little occasionally, but not enough to wake me up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on where the squeaks are.

If they are in the frame, tighten the joints, put a rubber washer between the metals being joined together. If you don't have a washer or can't adjust the bolts then lubricate the joint, normal cooking oil works, just put a little on and then make it squeak to try to get the oil to the squeak.

If it is in the springs, this is a bit harder. the easiest way is to get a board to go on top of them. but some people like the springs and this turns the bed into a non sprung bed. Otherwise find the bit that squeaks and either lubricate or replace.

Comment: Please don't use cooking oil as a lubricant. Vegetable oils will gum up, attract dirt and dust, and eventually end up a huge mess. It also spoils and goes rancid. Don't do it — [What happens if I use vegetable oil instead of machine oil or grease?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/7093/108)

Answer (score 0):

If the metal springs are exposed (not box springs), just lay a large sheet of rubber foam or foam-backed fabric over them. *Check that any material used is fire retardant*, since electric blankets, heaters or smoking could set it on fire.

Comment: The metal springs aren't exposed.

Answer (score 0):

W-D 40 or spray some Pam cooking spray on it any kind of spray oil .  You could make a small hole in the box springs and spray from there. I have done it before it worked great! You know mattresses don't last forever and you are actually suppose to replace them so often, so getting vegetable oil on the squeaking would certainly help, but you certainly don't have to drown the specifics in it, it only takes a little. A little dab will do you.

Comment: Vegetable oil is not the same as PAM. PAM cooking spray is not organic and will not become rancid. It's also good for drawers that bind. WD-40 is not a lubricant; but, is a good water displacement material. Both are bio-degradable.